# conditional probability theory

Tags: probability

For conditional probability,why does one event become the sample space for other event.Is it because that the other even should fall both in the first event and the  random experiment and gets influenced by the first event all together.? Can u explain this by analysis the example below.

For eg-Suppose If I have a bag containing 6 white and 4 red balls and if i choose two balls drawn one after another .

Let event A=Getting a white ball in first draw

Let event B=Getting  a red ball in second draw

So if i choose the a red ball with or without replacement and then choose a white ball ,will this be a conditional probability or not.Do we have to see the fact that event A and B are influencing each other.What about choosing 2 red ball similarly. I am so confused in this topic so it will a life saver for me for someone to explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this explains everything you're asking, but perhaps this is
a good place to start.

**With replacement.** If you get a white ball of the first draw (probability 6/10), and replace it, then the probability of a red ball on the second draw is
4/10. The second draw is independent of the first draw. $P(AB) = P(A)P(B) = 24/100.$

**Without replacement.** If you get a white ball on the first draw (probability 6/10) and do not replace it, then there 9 balls remaining in the bag, of which 4 are red. So the probability of a red ball on the second draw is 4/9. The second draw is dependent on the first. $P(AB) = P(A)P(B|A) = 24/90.$

Comment: So first case is of independent events and second of conditional probability.

Comment: That much is right.

Comment: can u tell me your approach towards identifying the cases as indpendent and conditional respectively?

Comment: In sampling with replacement, the bag is returned to its original condition after the first draw. So the second draw has the same probability as if it had been first. In sampling without replacement, the first draw alters the bag, and so the second draw is conditional on what happened on the first.

Comment: @harambe "Independent" is not a case distinct from "conditional". "Conditional" is everything. Only, in some situations, "conditional" simplifies into "independent".

Comment: So any two independent events do not influence the probabilities of each other but in conditional the opposite happens ,right?

Comment: I get what you are saying but i kinda suck in identifying events as conditional and indpendent

Comment: @harambe In both cases we have outcome $P(A)P(B\mid A)$. In the first case (independence) we also have $P(B\mid A)=P(B)$. There the events $A$ and $B$ are independent, i.e. we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Then consequently $P(B\mid A)=P(B)$.

Comment: Can we say that our sample space reduces from S(Total Outcomes) to Event B because it is a sure event?